# Find File Path with Several Words of the Name

Tags: python, filter, path, glob

my file name format is like this:

```
Apple price 04/13-04/15.xlsx
Apple price 04/16-04/18.xlsx
Orange price 04/13-04/15.xlsx
```

I'm now using the code as follows, using 'Apple' as filter. Is there anyway I can use double filter (also use 04/15 as filter)?

```
i = "Apple"
basePath = r'C:\Users\username\Desktop'
glob.glob(os.path.join(basePath,'*{0}*.xls'.format(i)))
```

Comment: Assuming the date will come after the fruit, you should be able to use `'*{0}*{1}*.xls'.format(fruit_filter, date_filter)`.

Comment: @FiddleStix it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What if you use regular expressions(re library) to filter so that you can add those in the same line.